# CMake error finding Boost headers

Tags: c++, boost, header, cmake

I'm having a problem with CMake finding Boost headers (specifically `thread`).

In my CMakeLists.txt file... (non-Boost related script omitted for brevity)

```
… 
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)

…

#this prints /Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost
MESSAGE(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}) 

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

…

target_link_libraries(MY_PROG ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY})
```

CMake configures and generates makefiles fine, but I get this compile error:

```
error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Thanks,
Dragonwrenn

P.S:  Here's the generated Makefile in case its useful

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canoncical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "/Applications/CMake 2.8-3.app/Contents/bin/cmake"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "/Applications/CMake 2.8-3.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E remove -f

# The program to use to edit the cache.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = "/Applications/CMake 2.8-3.app/Contents/bin/ccmake"

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/thomas/svn/simple-atlas-texture-generator

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/thomas/svn/simple-atlas-texture-generator/unix_makefiles

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    "/Applications/CMake 2.8-3.app/Contents/bin/ccmake" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    "/Applications/CMake 2.8-3.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/thomas/svn/simple-atlas-texture-generator/unix_makefiles/CMakeFiles /Users/thomas/svn/simple-atlas-texture-generator/unix_makefiles/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /Users/thomas/svn/simple-atlas-texture-generator/unix_makefiles/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named Atlas_Texture_Generator

# Build rule for target.
Atlas_Texture_Generator: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Atlas_Texture_Generator
.PHONY : Atlas_Texture_Generator

# fast build rule for target.
Atlas_Texture_Generator/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build
.PHONY : Atlas_Texture_Generator/fast

src/Controller.o: src/Controller.cpp.o
.PHONY : src/Controller.o

# target to build an object file
src/Controller.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/Controller.cpp.o
.PHONY : src/Controller.cpp.o

src/Controller.i: src/Controller.cpp.i
.PHONY : src/Controller.i

# target to preprocess a source file
src/Controller.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/Controller.cpp.i
.PHONY : src/Controller.cpp.i

src/Controller.s: src/Controller.cpp.s
.PHONY : src/Controller.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
src/Controller.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/Controller.cpp.s
.PHONY : src/Controller.cpp.s

src/ImageHandler.o: src/ImageHandler.cpp.o
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.o

# target to build an object file
src/ImageHandler.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/ImageHandler.cpp.o
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.cpp.o

src/ImageHandler.i: src/ImageHandler.cpp.i
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.i

# target to preprocess a source file
src/ImageHandler.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/ImageHandler.cpp.i
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.cpp.i

src/ImageHandler.s: src/ImageHandler.cpp.s
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
src/ImageHandler.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Atlas_Texture_Generator.dir/src/ImageHandler.cpp.s
.PHONY : src/ImageHandler.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... Atlas_Texture_Generator"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... src/Controller.o"
    @echo "... src/Controller.i"
    @echo "... src/Controller.s"
    @echo "... src/ImageHandler.o"
    @echo "... src/ImageHandler.i"
    @echo "... src/ImageHandler.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: Make sure you check `IF(Boost_THREAD_FOUND)` just to be sure it's finding it properly. Try using `Boost_LIBRARIES` also (description in my version of FindBoost.cmake is "Link these to use the Boost libraries that you specified, not cached").

Comment: Also, what's the output of `MESSAGE("${Boost_ERROR_REASON}")` after running find_package?

Comment: @darvidsOn:  The Boost thread library was found.
Using Boost_LIBRARIES has no noticeable effect.  ${Boost_ERROR_REASON} is blank.

Comment: So, what does the generated makefile look like?  And does the file "/Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost/boost/thread.hpp" exist?

Comment: I agree with @Benjamin, the best way to check whether you've specified CMakeLists options correctly is to view the `g++` line for your source file in the generated Makefile and check if `-I /Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost` is present. If not, you haven't properly specified boost as a header search path.

Comment: @darvids:  I didn't see Boost in the Makefile, but I posted it in case its useful.  I have no experience with raw Makefiles.

Comment: @Lindley:  the path doesn't appear in the Makefile, but it definitely exists.

Comment: i think your Boost_INCLUDE_DIR should be `/Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost/include/` instead of `/Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost`.

Comment: Aditya: I think you're almost there, but it should be /Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/ instead. That directory will contain boost/thread.hpp At least, that's how it more or less is on my machine. @dragonwrenn Worth a check?

Comment: @Bart- that's it!  Fixed!  Thanks very much.  Put your comment into an answer so I can accept it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error states `error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory`, your Boost_INCLUDE_DIR should be changed from `/Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0/boost` to `/Users/thomas/boost_1_47_0`

That should solve the problem.